# Can you search GitHub PRs by authors in a team?

Tags: github

Is it possible to search GitHub PRs for PRs created by someone in a given team?

For example, you can currently search by author: `author:<username>`

Is there some way of doing something similar but search for all PRs authored by someone in some given team? Something like (and this is invalid, but) `author:<teamname>`. I know you can add the team as a reviewer, but we touch files in a bunch of different places so it would be hard to automate it.

The use case is that our team works in a large monorepo and we would like to be able to filter for the PRs relevant to our team.